# Human body reaction to gamma rays

Tags: human-biology

I attended a meeting where the speaker claimed that a human body reacts to the exposition to gamma rays reducing the amount of acetylcholine. Is this thing scientifically proven? I cannot find any source that confirm this thesis.

**- Update -**
The source from which the speaker based his theory is [this paper](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/cog/aetr/1993/00000018/00000001/art00005).
 Excluding the fact that here gamma rays seem not to be mentioned, is this a reliable source?